# Contact form with attachment invisible error

Tags: php, email-attachments, contact-form-7

I have this contact form with file attachment, it works well when i attach a file and fill all form, but when i try to send without attachment, i getting a "white page", but there's the same form just invisible, and i get the message "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."

I think missing everywhere the "if"

```
<?php
    
    // debug
error_reporting(E_ALL); // Ez a report all errors
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get the submitted form data

    $name = trim($_POST['name']); 
    $email = trim($_POST['email']); 
    $dropdown = trim($_POST['dropdown']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']); 
 
    //validation for email
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
    if (!preg_match($email_exp, $email)) {
        echo "<p style='color:red;'>A megadott E-mail cím érvénytelen.</p>";
        exit;
    }
   
    
    // Upload attachment file
    if(!empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])){
        foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $key => $val) {
    
            $fileerror = $_FILES['attachment']['error'][$key]; // get the error (if any)
            //validate form field for attaching the file
            if($fileerror > 0)
            {
                echo "<p style='color:red;'>Feltöltési hiba vagy Nincs fájl feltöltve.</p>";
                exit;
            }
             
            // Attachment path config
            $targetDir = "uploads/";
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$key]);
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
             
            // Allow certain attachment formats
            $allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg');
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                // Check the attachment size
                if ($_FILES['attachment']['size'][$key] > 6000000) {
                    echo "<p style='color:red;'>A csatolt kép nem haladhatja meg a 6MB-ot</p>";
                    exit;
                }else{
                    // Upload attachment to the server
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$key], $targetFilePath)){
                        $uploadedFile = $targetFilePath;
                    }else{
                        echo "<p style='color:red;'>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.</p>";
                        exit;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                echo "<p style='color:red;'>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, & PNG files are allowed to upload.</p>";
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //If everything above is ok then move further 
 
    //Use PHPmailer
    require "phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->Encoding = "16bit";
 
    //Mailbody to send in an email
    $mailbody ='';
 
    //Sender email address
    $sender = "";     // Gmail SMTP username
    $mail->isSMTP();                  // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;               //See errors, change it to 4
    $mail->Host = '';   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;           // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = $sender;        // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';// Gmail SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';        // Enable TLS encryption, `SSL` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                // TCP port to connect to  
 
    $mail->setFrom($sender, $name); 
 
    $mail->addAddress('pixelkontakthu@gmail.com', 'PixelKontakt');     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addAddress('name@example.com'); //add more recipient (optional)
    $mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
    //$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    //$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
 
    //Add attachment 

    if(is_array($_FILES)) {
        foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $key => $val) {
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$key]);
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
            $uploadedFile = $targetFilePath;
            $mail->AddAttachment($uploadedFile, $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$key], 'base64', 'mime/type');
        }
    }

 
    $mail->isHTML(true);    // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
    $mail->Subject = $dropdown.'-ra jelentkezett '.$name;
    $mail->Body = $mailbody;
    //$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
 
    //Email your contact form data with an attachment using Gmail SMTP with PHPMailer
    if(!$mail->send()){
        echo "<p style='color:red;'>Message could not be sent. Please try again.</p>";
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        echo "<p style='color:green;'>Üzenet sikeresen elküldve!</p>";
        //To delete all sent files from the uploaded folder;
        foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $key => $val) {
            $fileName = basename($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$key]);
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
            $uploadedFile = $targetFilePath;
            @unlink($uploadedFile);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I tried to figure out this part unsuccessfully:

```
// Upload attachment file
    if(!empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])){
        foreach ($_FILES["attachment"]["name"] as $key => $val) {
```

Comment: ___Little Note___ PHP automatically removes the remporary file so you dont need to do the `//To delete all sent files from the uploaded folder;`

Comment: Check your PHP error log for a warning from `move_uploaded_file()` to find out why it's failing.

Comment: Its always a good idea to check [`$_FILES['attachment']['error'].`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) before deciding how to proceed

Comment: @RiggsFolly you right! I deleted the "attachment validators" since that's how I want it, it should work without an attachment